# Wix v3 Bundle can run two instances simultaneously, how can I prevent this?

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11

We have a Wix v3 Installer MSI that is contained in a Wix Bundle alongside other pre-requisite programs.

I am able to open multiple intances of the GUI (which is fine) but I am also allowed to then agree to terms and initiate installation on **both** open instances.

Eventually both installations fail (again this is fine). But **is there a way to prevent the opening of multiple instances in the first place, or to prevent the installation starting if one is already underway?**

Because Wix projects have their own type I can't use the same approach as C# desktop application to restrict the number of open instances. I could use a script file to prevent the opening of two instances of my program but in my opinion this is not really a suitable solution when it comes to deploying a product on customer computers. Really I am looking for a clean and reliable solution that could be used in our end product, not something that is only really suitable on a development computer.

Answer (score 0):

Sure. Your custom BoostrapperApplication could use something like a named mutex to block other installations from starting. Note: this scenario isn't as easy as it seems at first glance because you need to consider how to handle upgrades and other related bundle interactions. For example, you don't want to prevent the old bundle from being uninstalled because the new bundle is still running.